# Magento admin category Tabs: general or General Information

Tags: group, tabs

I am creating a module that slots in a new field in the category editor.

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'mapped_objects', array(
    'group'             => 'General Information',
    'type'              => 'text',
    'backend'           => '',
    'input_renderer'    => '',
    'label'             => 'Mapped Data',
    'class'             => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'is_configurable'   => false,
    'order'             => 99999
));
```

The issue is that it would seem that some magento versions use 'General' and some 'General Information' for the Group name.

Can anyone pinpoint when this changed? (which versions are 'general' and which are 'general information')

TIA

Comment: Would still like to know when it changed, but I have adjusted my code to not care. The correct group name can be found using this code:
`
$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$group = $installer->getAttributeGroup($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, 'attribute_group_name');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.57-0.7.58.php`
`line 84`

That will be the `Mage_Catalog` module's version. You can determine the magento version from it yourself.